# How to find the value in the same row of the value of percentage change

Tags: python, pandas

I am using `spyder`. I have imported `pandas` and did

```py
df = pd.read_csv
```

This is my csv file:

```py
Year  Public Specialist  Public Non-Specialist  Private Specialist  Private Non-Specialist
0  2010               1996                   3184                1151                    2159
1  2011               2165                   3456                1229                    2220
2  2012               2342                   3789                1293                    2222
3  2013               2511                   4150                1351                    2327
4  2014               2829                   4501                1411                    2379
5  2015               3052                   4857                1470                    2444
6  2016               3299                   5059                1485                    2494
7  2017               3523                   5050                1528                    2579
8  2018               3741                   5078                1565                    2660
9  2019               3864                   5166                1682                    2757
```

Here is the code:

```py
print(f"Highest percentage change is {df.iloc[:,4].pct_change().max(axis=0):.2f}% in "
      f"{df.loc[df['Private Non-Specialist'] == df.iloc[:,4].pct_change().max(axis=0), 'Year'].values[0]}")
```

After `in`, I'm trying to find the year which has the highest percentage change, but the output shows:

```
index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0
```

Comment: Hello, can split up the print statement into multiple variables to make it clearer where the error is coming from.  I also think adding a code block would make this question more readable: https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO! Please take a look at [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). It will be useful for you and the community.

Comment: please provide the data or an example data set such that we can provide a proper solution.

Comment: added the data set

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a solution. Added a couple of steps for clarity:

```
max_change = df["Private Non-Specialist"].pct_change().max()

max_inx = df["Private Non-Specialist"].pct_change().idxmax()
max_year = df.iloc[max_inx]["Year"]

print(f"Highest percentage change is {max_change:.2f}% in {max_year}")
```

This prints:

```
Highest percentage change is 0.05% in 2013
```